# Unable to send email to people in Google+ circles

Tags: gmail, google-plus, google-contacts

Recently, a Google [blog post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/reach-people-you-know-more-easily.html) announced that one can now send emails to people in their Google+ circles. I am able to do that from my main GMail account but a new account I created doesn't have access to this feature. Is there something one needs to do on a new account to enable this feature?

I should also mention that the option *Who can email you via your Google+ profile?* in settings is available but just that when composing email, suggestions from G+ connections are not shown.

Comment: Perhaps it hasn't rolled out to everyone yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can only email people who you already have them in your Google+ circles. If you created a new Gmail account, then to be able to email people you know from Google+ you should create a Google+ profile using your new account, then add those people to your circles (using this new profile) and then you will be able to email them using your new Gmail account

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to enable. Once it's enabled on the account you will have access.